# making specific request with httr

Tags: r, curl, httr

How would I make this request with `httr`?

```
'curl -X POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer 21318318usdhsdha9283718 " \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data "{\"path\": \"/today/\",\"recursive\": false,\"include_media_info\": false,\"include_deleted\": false}"'
```

I have tried using `curlconverter` but hasn't worked well for this one. I am not sure how I would go about implementing the --data parameter and what follows.

Comment: You should remove your token out of your question.

Comment: its a fake token naturally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me, does it work for you?

```
httr::POST(
  "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder",
  add_headers(Authorization = "Bearer <token>"),
  content_type_json(),
  body = "{\"path\": \"/folder\",\"recursive\": false,\"include_media_info\": false,\"include_deleted\": false}",
  encode = "json"
)
```

If you want to generalize a bit for many folders:

```
library("httr")
foobar <- function(x) {
  content(POST(
    "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder",
    add_headers(Authorization = "Bearer <token>"),
    content_type_json(),
    body = list(path = paste0("/", x), recursive = FALSE, 
                include_media_info = FALSE, include_deleted = FALSE),
    encode = "json"
  ))
}

lapply(c('a', 'b', "c"), foobar)
```

Comment: thank you. Where would you recommend that I go to if I wish to learn more about how to better structure my curl requests into httr? I had no idea that the contents of the data parameter could just be put into body

Comment: another small question. If you had a variable as opposed to the folder string, how would you concatenate it in there? I've been having some trouble with paste()....

Comment: `httr` has a few vignettes https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/httr/ - I've blogged about the various curl options using `httr`  https://ropensci.org/blog/2014/12/18/curl-options/ - for the variable question I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: Thank you so much for your blog! Sorry for the lack of clarification. I'm looping over folder names so I'd like to inserts a variable instead of the string 'folder' in the body parameter. I've been having trouble using paste inside of the httr function though. How would you concatenate a string and a variable inside?

Comment: Oh I see. I was surrounding the parameters with paste(). Makes sense why it wasn't working. Thank you so much!

Comment: no problem, and you can see in the second code block i just used an R list which is probably easier to read, and works just like the json input